# Cucumber - Is it possible to share a table between Scenarios?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

Does anyone know its its possible to define a table once in a .feature file & then access it from multiple scenarios? I'm not chaining scenarios but many of them do need to pass tables with the same data to their step definitions - also for this reason examples won't really do what I need here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to tag all your scenarious where you need a table:

```
@given_have_table
Scenario: test
  Then I am happy
```

Then bind `Before` hook to this tag and call step that declares your table from within `Before` hook definition:

```
Before("@given_have_table") do
  steps Q%{
  Given I have the following table:
    | a | b |
    | 1 | 2 |
  }
end
```

Alternative approach is to construct required table in tagged `Before` hook without calling step:

```
Before("@given_have_table") do
  @tbl = { :a => 1, :b => 2 }
end
```