# In a scenario, how do I tell my tests to randomly select a step from a specified set of possible steps?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, capybara

I have many steps, each of which will click on a button corresponding to one of many possible behaviors. I am looking for a way to tell my scenarios to randomly choose a step from a set of steps. Here's what the steps look like:

```
I click on 'Taking photos' on <device>
I click on 'Listening to music' on <device>
I click on 'Being productive' on <device>
I click on 'Social media' on <device>
I click on 'Gaming' on <device>
I click on 'Watching videos' on <device>
```

So when I run my scenario, I would like a way for it to read something like this:

```
Given   I set the viewport to <device>
When    I go to the homepage on <device>
And     I click on Get started on <device>
And     <random step from the above set of steps>
```

Ideally, there would be a way to prevent it from re-using a step that has already been used in this session as well. I have no idea how to go about implementing something like this. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: What is the goal of this scenario? It's not quite clear. Do you want to execute all the steps in the same scenario, in a random order. Or execute one step in a series of scenarios?

Comment: I do not want to execute all the steps in the same scenario. I'd like it to be flexible enough that I can perhaps run 3 of the steps in one scenario, then 4 in another identically structured scenario. I just no idea how to begin implementing the logic for it to randomly select from a pool of possible steps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking at this backwards, instead of looking at your target steps as 6 different steps, it's really one step. Although, this solution should work the same regardless.

```
I click on '<button/tab/whatevs>' on <device>
```

Now have another scenario that is handling the random calls.

```
And I randomly click on 3 to 5 of the following items on <device>:
 | item                 |
 | 'Taking photos'      |
 | 'Listening to music' |
 | 'Watching videos'    |
 | 'Being productive'   |
 | 'Checking email'     |

The step def for these would look something like:

When /I randomly click on 3 to 5 of the following behaviors on <device>:/ do |min, max, device, items|
  num_clicks = rand(min..max) # get your random number of clicks in the range
  random_behaviors = items.sample(num_clicks) # use sample to pull your random amount (maybe need to massage items as it will be a cucumber table and I don't know if it answers to sample)
  random_behaviors.each do |behavior|
    step %{
      I click on '#{behavior}' on #{device}
    }
  end
end
```

Bonus: Check out this question about sharing a data table between scenarios. That I think would allow you to stash your 12 item configuration somewhere.
[Cucumber - Is it possible to share a table between Scenarios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899053/cucumber-is-it-possible-to-share-a-table-between-scenarios)

Comment: I hadn't thought about approaching it this way before. This is promising, but this still requires me to dictate to cucumber exactly which buttons to click on and in which order. The reason I wanted to randomize the selection of these buttons is because after selecting 3 or more of these behavior buttons, you can proceed to a results page which displays a list of recommended items based on what was entered. There are a total of 12 behaviors, and selection of a minimum of 3 is required to proceed to results.

Comment: So the user can select anywhere between 3 and 12 behaviors, and this will affect the list of results. Even the order in which behaviors are selected will affect results. To extensively test the accuracy of the results, I wanted a way to randomize which behaviors and how many behaviors are selected during testing.

Comment: updated the answer to better reflect your situation. Also shared a link that shows a way to share a datatable across scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber isn't really the right tool for doing exhaustive testing, so if you are considering doing this for every possible combination of actions you should think about writing a lower level test in a programming language.

If you use Cucumber as intended, to drive the development of this application. You can probably use very simple scenarios to get you to the point where you would like to to more exhaustive testing. Perhaps something like

```
Given I am on my ipad
When I make some choices
Then I should see a recommendation
```

This would be improved if you explained 'why' the user is making these choices, perhaps by naming the set of choices e.g.

```
When I make some lifestyle choices
When I choose things I like to do
```

and doing the same thing with the recommendations.

You can make steps like this work by doing the programming lower down in the step definitions or, ideally, in helper methods that the step definitions call. Here because you are in a programming language you can easily do things like randomization.

When you have got something that kinda captures the business idea of what you want to do, then you can use TDD and unit tests to drive things like ensuring the 'correct' recomendations are made.